# Get chrome storage value set in one file, in another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to retrieve values set in chrome storage.  The original value was stored using a different script in the same extension.

The value stored was stored using:

`chrome.storage.sync.set({
    logoStore: logolink})`

Then I am using below to retrieve the storage value and replace the image url. No doubt the entirely incorrect method, syntax and all. :(

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('logoStore', function (result) {
        alert(logoStore.result);
   });
   var logourl = logoStore.result;

// ======= SWAP IMAGES ==========
var images = document.getElementsByTagName ("img");
var x=0;
while(x<images.length)
{
if(images[x].src == "https://www.this-url.com/images/new-brand-2016/common/logo-2016-246x48-v1.gif")
{
images[x].src = 'logourl';
}
x=x+1;
}
```

I'm very new to js, and have searched extensively on SO and elsewhere for the correct method to use the stored values.  Sorry for such a noob question.

On an upnote - I did manage to resolve my last question with help and some further efforts myself :)  Thanks.

========= UPDATE =========

I got this part working thanks to your input :)

Working code for this is...

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['logoStore'], function(result) {
     console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
          var logourl = result.logoStore;

// ======= SWAP IMAGES ==========
var images = document.getElementsByTagName ("img");
var x=0;
while(x<images.length)
{
if(images[x].src == "https://www.url.com/images/new/common/logo-246x48-v1.gif")
{
images[x].src = logourl;
}
x=x+1;
}
        });
```

Next Step...

Now I have to get two more values from storage and insert them into existing HTML.

I can successfully get the first value to load, but it is breaking my inline style, and the second value is not loading.

Code below.

```js
// ========== ADD HEADER TEXT ==============

 chrome.storage.sync.get(['companyStore', 'dataStore'], function(result) {
     console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    var company = result.companyStore;
      var data = result.dataStore;

var el = document.querySelector('table.delivery-address');

// get element content as string
console.log(el.innerHTML)

// prepend to the element's content
el.innerHTML = '</table><div style="margin-right:0px;float:right;text-align:right;margin-top:20px;"><h2 style="font-size: 28px;">Info</h2><br/><p style="font-size:18px;line-height:1.4em;"><b>' + company; + '</b><br/>' + data; + '<b></p></div><br/><br/><table class="delivery-address">' + el.innerHTML;

});
```

Comment: Have you tried placing all the code **inside** the callback function?

Comment: Ok, I'm researching that now - no idea how to add a callback.  Does the rest of that code look ok then?

Comment: @GMaiolo - sorry I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: The callback is the function that you are passing as the 2nd argument of the `chrome.storage.local.get`

Comment: Please refer this url for more clarifiaction. Check if you are getting any chrome.runtime.lastError. http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/JavaScript.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get.html

Also, try to use chrome.storage.sync.get.

Comment: Ok, that step is working, next step is requiring getting two values.  I have updated the question. The new detail is at the bottom.  Thanks for your help on this everyone.

Comment: You were setting in `sync` but reading `local`. As for "next step", it's apparently a different question so you shouldn't modify the original one - revert it and post your working code as an answer, then click the button to accept it as a solution.

Comment: While prepend to the element's content, you are using `;` after the `company` variable and that is why the code line terminates there and do not execute the remaining line. `;` (semicolon) is used in the end of the line where it is logically ended. Therefore remove the semicolon from the `company;` and `data;`.